# What is the solution to the Squirrel sequence of letters question?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm at the part where I am asked to complete a sequence of 7 letters and a question mark. I simply just don't understand what I am supposed to do. Can I get some help?

Comment: You can just guess. Trial and error in alphabetical order netted me the correct answer very quickly.

Answer (score 4):

`SIEDNA? -> ?ANDIES`

Does this help?

> The answer is `C` to make `CANDIES`

Answer (score 1):

look in a mirror.

It is spelling a word backwards